# How to get the href value of an anchor tag with javascript from a string

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the href value of last anchor tag in the string content below, with pure javascript, without Jquery.

```
var contents = '<div id="content"><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg"><img title="Ruffcoin-Made-In-Aba.jpg" class="alignnone size-full" alt="image" src="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg" /></a>↵↵↵↵Indigenous heavyweight, <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/ruffcoin">Ruffcoin</a> recently dropped a new album titled “Made In Aba“. I’ve been giving it a few spins, and I must say, the album is quite solid.↵↵[matrix]↵↵Two of my early faves are “Aba Made” and “Higher Higher which feature <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/sparkle">Sparkle</a>)”. You should check ’em out, then download on iTunes <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/made-in-aba/id1180901826?ign-mpt=uo%3D4"><strong>hereq</strong></a>.↵↵Cop below.↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin - Aba Made</a></strong>↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin ft Sparkle - Higher Higher</a></strong></div>';
```

this is the section I want to get

```
href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3"
```

Comment: What did you try? How to you get that string? Is it part of the DOM? Lots of missing information here

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelector('div a:last-of-type'))` should give you all the attributes of the last a inside a div, you could narrow that down by adding a class or id to the parent div too, prone to errors tho but it's on the right track

Comment: Parse the HTML into a DOM element, traverse/query the element to get the `<a>` element and access its `href` attribute.

Comment: You can achieve that easier using regex, see my answer below :)

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni - not a safe solution

Comment: @mplungjan: What do you mean?

Comment: Others have posted why not to use regex to parse HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [create an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and insert the HTML string into it, you can manipulate the HTML using the usual DOM methods getElementsByTagName or querySelector/querySelectorAll:

```js
var contents = '<div id="content"><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg"><img title="Ruffcoin-Made-In-Aba.jpg" class="alignnone size-full" alt="image" src="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg" /></a>↵↵↵↵Indigenous heavyweight, <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/ruffcoin">Ruffcoin</a> recently dropped a new album titled “Made In Aba“. I’ve been giving it a few spins, and I must say, the album is quite solid.↵↵[matrix]↵↵Two of my early faves are “Aba Made” and “Higher Higher which feature <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/sparkle">Sparkle</a>)”. You should check ’em out, then download on iTunes <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/made-in-aba/id1180901826?ign-mpt=uo%3D4"><strong>hereq</strong></a>.↵↵Cop below.↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin - Aba Made</a></strong>↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin ft Sparkle - Higher Higher</a></strong></div>';

var snippet = document.createElement("div");
snippet.innerHTML=contents;
var links = snippet.getElementsByTagName("a"),
    lastURL = links[links.length-1].href; // or getAttribute("href")
console.log(lastURL);
```

Comment: yes @mplungjan  i want to know, please can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
var contents = '<div id="content"><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg"><img title="Ruffcoin-Made-In-Aba.jpg" class="alignnone size-full" alt="image" src="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg" /></a>↵↵↵↵Indigenous heavyweight, <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/ruffcoin">Ruffcoin</a> recently dropped a new album titled “Made In Aba“. I’ve been giving it a few spins, and I must say, the album is quite solid.↵↵[matrix]↵↵Two of my early faves are “Aba Made” and “Higher Higher which feature <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/sparkle">Sparkle</a>)”. You should check ’em out, then download on iTunes <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/made-in-aba/id1180901826?ign-mpt=uo%3D4"><strong>hereq</strong></a>.↵↵Cop below.↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin - Aba Made</a></strong>↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin ft Sparkle - Higher Higher</a></strong></div>';

var hrefs = contents.match(/href="([^"]*)/g);
var href = hrefs[hrefs.length-1];
console.log(href);
```

Comment: what is contents? ignore me I didn't see it :)

Comment: If you refer to the question, it is the variable asker used

Comment: Yea sorry pal, tired eyes make for bad comments :)

Comment: This code results in `href="http://................` - another good reason not to use RegEx to parse HTML and a good reason to create snippets to test code

Answer (score 3):

Generate a [temporary element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)(or use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)) with the html content and get the attribute of a tag within it.

```js
var contents = '<div id="content"><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg"><img title="Ruffcoin-Made-In-Aba.jpg" class="alignnone size-full" alt="image" src="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg" /></a>↵↵↵↵Indigenous heavyweight, <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/ruffcoin">Ruffcoin</a> recently dropped a new album titled “Made In Aba“. I’ve been giving it a few spins, and I must say, the album is quite solid.↵↵[matrix]↵↵Two of my early faves are “Aba Made” and “Higher Higher which feature <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/sparkle">Sparkle</a>)”. You should check ’em out, then download on iTunes <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/made-in-aba/id1180901826?ign-mpt=uo%3D4"><strong>hereq</strong></a>.↵↵Cop below.↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin - Aba Made</a></strong>↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin ft Sparkle - Higher Higher</a></strong></div>';

var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = contents;

// if you want to get a tag within strong tag
console.log(
  temp.querySelector('strong a').getAttribute('href')
);

// if you want to get the last link
var ele = temp.getElementsByTagName('a');
console.log(
  ele[ele.length - 1].getAttribute('href')
);
```

Comment: It could be achieved easier using regex.

Comment: If it was pure HTML yes, but this is a string. So why to parse it then query it? at least regex get it in one step.

Comment: @PranavCBalan : The asker isn't trying to parse HTML, he is try to get a string from another, this is why regex is more proper in my opinion :)

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni : I will give you a small example string and try it with regex......  `<a href="/hi"> href="fdfdf" </a>`

Comment: I see your point, but if the string contains invalid html it won't be parse-able too, every solution has its ups and downs. But I answered regarding the exact case asked. Thanks for the enlightenment :)

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni : please go through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Sir, that is a different case, that is asking about parsing HTML by regex, not finding a string in a string using regex. That is appreciated but I see it as a totally different case :)

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni : I don't prefer regex to parse HTML.... it may work here but at some point, it may fail or will be more complex :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the string comes from a trusted source you could just pop it into a div and use DOM functions, like so:

```js
var contents = '<div id="content"><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg"><img title="Ruffcoin-Made-In-Aba.jpg" class="alignnone size-full" alt="image" src="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg" /></a>↵↵↵↵Indigenous heavyweight, <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/ruffcoin">Ruffcoin</a> recently dropped a new album titled “Made In Aba“. I’ve been giving it a few spins, and I must say, the album is quite solid.↵↵[matrix]↵↵Two of my early faves are “Aba Made” and “Higher Higher which feature <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/sparkle">Sparkle</a>)”. You should check ’em out, then download on iTunes <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/made-in-aba/id1180901826?ign-mpt=uo%3D4"><strong>hereq</strong></a>.↵↵Cop below.↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin - Aba Made</a></strong>↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin ft Sparkle - Higher Higher</a></strong></div>';
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = contents;

var anchorTags = Array.prototype.slice.call(container.getElementsByTagName('a')); // Get all anchor tags && convert collection to array
console.log(anchorTags.pop().href); // Get last anchor tag and log its href property
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var contents = '<div id="content"><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg"><img title="Ruffcoin-Made-In-Aba.jpg" class="alignnone size-full" alt="image" src="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ruffcoin-made-in-aba.jpg" /></a>↵↵↵↵Indigenous heavyweight, <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/ruffcoin">Ruffcoin</a> recently dropped a new album titled “Made In Aba“. I’ve been giving it a few spins, and I must say, the album is quite solid.↵↵[matrix]↵↵Two of my early faves are “Aba Made” and “Higher Higher which feature <a href="http://www.okhype.com/tag/sparkle">Sparkle</a>)”. You should check ’em out, then download on iTunes <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/made-in-aba/id1180901826?ign-mpt=uo%3D4"><strong>hereq</strong></a>.↵↵Cop below.↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_-_Aba_Made_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin - Aba Made</a></strong>↵↵[audio mp3="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3"][/audio]<strong><a href="http://www.okhype.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Ruffcoin_ft_Sparkle_-_Higher_Higher_Okhype.com_.mp3">DOWNLOAD Ruffcoin ft Sparkle - Higher Higher</a></strong></div>';

// Create element that will temporarially house the elements in the string
var temp = document.createElement('div');

// Convert the string to child elements
temp.innerHTML = contents;

// Get all the links
var links = temp.querySelectorAll("a");

// Get the contents of the href attribute of the last link:
console.log(links[links.length-1].href);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
  var links = snippet.getElementsByTagName("a");
  links(links.length - 1).getAttribute('href');
```